# jQuery queries on variables fails in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The following code returns the html of the selected element contained in the `data` variable in all the major browsers, except IE.

```
$("#blapp", data).html();
```

Does anyone know why?

A workaround is to insert the `data` into the DOM, select the wanted data and then subsequently remove the temp stuff. I was though wondering if anyone knows a better solution?

Comment: Why don't you post what your `'SELECTOR'` is?

Comment: Can you post the content of `data`? Perhaps some invalid markup that IE can't deal with?

Comment: The `data` is really just the page content itself without headers and footers. The selector works beautifully on the page itself, but returns null on the data variable. One thing though is that since the return data doesn't give any doctype IE puts it in quirks mode, does that affect jQuery results?

Comment: Does the `data` include `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` elements? If so, see my answer.

Comment: `Data` does not include `html`, `head`, `body`

Answer (score 0):

I've got a gut feeling that `data` is an entire HTML document. If so, you'll get different results between browsers when trying to make a jQuery object out of it.

If that's the case, try this instead:

```
$('<div>' + data + '</div>').find( '#blapp' ).html();
```

Another option would be to try using `.filter()` instead of `.find()` (which you're doing now via the context argument). Although this may cause it to stop working in some browsers.

```
$(data).filter('#blapp').html();
```

Comment: None of those options return anything but null.

Comment: @Torstein: Just in IE, right? If that's the case, I can't tell without more information.